# Memory leak in min-max algorithm

Tags: c, memory-leaks, minimax

I'm completely new to programming, I have just picked up C a month ago in the completely random attempt to code my own chess engine (my goal being to create something that can best myself. fascinating.) so please try to be as clear as possible with your answers and please ask for clarifications when my explanation is lacking.

At the moment my engine can analyze around 0.5 to 0.8 million positions per second on my 1.8Ghz processor, any ideas on that would be welcome too but anyway it looked obvious to me that the only way to make my engine faster was to try moves in fixed order so that bad moves will just be excluded from the search.
In order to do that I changed my code from passing `int` variables into passing `int` pointers. My idea being to just stick to the score the move that generated it. The code still works but grows in size. I have googled and tried some memory leak tools but they only tell me where the leaked memory has been allocated, which I already know, but not when it's address has been lost.

I've figured that if I just post my code some guy with experience could just spot the leak right away.
Now that I have hit the Internet looking for help I have found out that my code is logically equivalent to an algorithm that has existed for decades under the name of minimax with alpha beta pruning. Cool.

```
int evaluate(int *board, int capture) { ... return board evaluation; }

int *Black(int *board, int depth, int *max, int *min) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        temp = malloc(20 * sizeof(int)); //eventually i will store
    }                 
    minlocal = malloc(20 * sizeof(int)); //moves next to the score
    *minlocal = *min;  //this is what i came up with so that min/max        
                       //of a higher function call doesn't get changed
    for (all moves) {
        if (depth > 0) {
            temp = whitemove(board, depth - 1, max, minlocal);
        } else {
            *temp = evaluate(board, capture);
        }
        if (*temp <= *max) {
            ;free(minlocal);
            return temp;
        }
        if (*temp < *minlocal) {
            *minlocal = *temp;
        }
        if (depth > 0) {
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    if (depth = 0) {    //<====== silly bug!
        free(temp);
    }
    return minlocal;
}

int *whitemove(int *board, int depth, int *max, int *min) {
    temp = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    maxlocal = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    *temp = -30000;
    *maxlocal = *max;
    for (all moves) {
        v = blackmove(board, depth - 1, maxlocal, min);
        if (*v > *temp) {
            free(temp);
            temp = v;
        } else {
            free(v);
        }
        if (*temp > *maxlocal) {
            *maxlocal = *temp;
        }
        if (*temp >= *min) {
            free(maxlocal);
            return temp;
        }
    }
    free(maxlocal);
    return temp;
}
```

Reading the code you probably noticed that my thing can only play white and depth can only be an even number, this doesn't matter to me for now.

As far as I know this approach I took might be absolutely dumb, but it doesn't seem to be any slower than before and it should be able to store lines of play instead of a the simple first move. Any opinion on alternatives is welcome as well.

Comment: Too chatty. Sorry, but this is a Q&A site; your history/motivation/color of your car is not relevant. Instead you should have formatted your code properly; it currently is hardly readable. You should have added the relevant parts. Learn [ask], provide a [mcve]. And learn using a debugger.

Comment: Stylistic hint: you don't *need* to malloc here. 2*20*100 ints will fit in automatic storage (you could even use a global array and index that) will probably be faster, too.

Comment: @Olad Where is OP asking about a car?

Comment: OP, what is your question? There is not a single sentence ending in a question mark in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have picked up good programming skills in C in a very short time.

Yet you still need to improve your style: presentation is **very** important as it helps avoid many stupid bugs and makes your code more readable to both other programmers ans yourself.

Also use all warnings tha compiler can produce with the appropriate flags, such as `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.

There is a silly bug at the end of the `Black` function:

```
if (depth = 0)
```

Should obviously read

```
 if (depth == 0)
```

This is where you never free the memory.

There might be other places where you lose track of allocated blocks, as well as places where allocation is not required, using a local array is much quicker if you do not need to return it to the caller.  Passing a pointer to a local array as a destination array could also reduce the amount of memory allocation.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. can't believe i spent hours trying to figure out the logic flaw and couldn't see the obvious typo. thank you for the hints on the warnings as well

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you are writing code in C, whenever you allocate memory, you need to keep in mind that you need to [free](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) it correctly, using double equals operator in your comparison. In our case, you have a variable called `temp`, which will use allocated memory and upon each initialization for `whitemove` or `Black`, you allocate new memory for it, without `free`ing the previously allocated memory, which remains allocated, but you no longer have reference for it.

The answer is above, below I will give you a few suggestions:

It is nice that you invented the alpha-beta pruning without learning about it, but you need to implement it elegantly. For instance, you have a `whitemove` and a `Black` function. Why do you name `Black` as "Black" instead of being consistent and naming it "blackmove"? Furthermore, when you write a function, you need to solve the problem as generally as possible. How is a white move different from black's?

- they try to maximize the evaluation towards different directions
- they are able to move with different pieces

Now, if you take that into account, you can write the two functions as a single function. You do not need to return large memory chunks, because that is not what we intend to know from a chess engine. You need to return the evaluation and the move. You could use a single array to store the best variation and another array to store the current variation. Whenever you find a better variation then the one previously considered the best, then replace it. But avoid memory leaks :)